# ORACLE PL/SQL TRIGGER : Insert if condition is true and when false prevent insert

Tags: plsql, triggers, insert

So, I'm working on a school projet and I **have** to do a trigger. My idea was, that I don't want to insert more than 3 rows if the date is "sysdate".

But I keep getting this error, the first one is my exception, but I don't know what are the two others ? -> [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiUpp.png)

```
create or replace trigger t_vehiculeEntretien
  after insert
  on esi_entretien
declare
  v_count integer(10);
  exception_name EXCEPTION; 
 
begin
  SELECT COUNT(ENT_ID_VEHICULE)
  INTO v_count
  FROM ESI_ENTRETIEN
  WHERE DATEDEBUT_ENTRETIEN = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD,mm,YYYY');
  
  IF v_count > 3 THEN
    RAISE exception_name;
  END IF;
  
  
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN exception_name THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Il y a un maximum de 3 entretiens programmé le jour même'); 
  
end t_vehiculeEntretien;
```

Comment: Everything is OK; that's just the full error stack Oracle displays when error occurs.

Comment: Oh okay thank you ! 
( I’m a noob ahah )